# Backbonejs fullcalendar v2 load events from localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, local-storage, fullcalendar

How can I load data from local-storage to new version of fullcalendar through backbone collection?

**My localstorage data:**

```
  if(localStorage.getItem('events') == null){
    var events = [
    {"title":"Event 1","start":"2014-09-13T04:00:00.000Z","end":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","creator":432,"backgroundColor":"rgb(190, 219, 5","allDay":"true"},
    {"title":"Event 2","start":"2014-09-28T11:30:00.000Z","end":"2014-09-28T19:30:00.000Z","creator":432,"backgroundColor":"rgb(190, 219, 5","allDay":""},
    {"title":"Event 3","start":"2014-09-09T04:00:00.000Z","end":"2014-09-11T04:00:00.000Z","creator":432,"backgroundColor":"rgb(31, 138, 11","allDay":"true"}
    ];
    localStorage.setItem('events',JSON.stringify(events));
}
```

**Here is my view :**

```
define([
'underscore',
'backbone',
'models/event/Event',
'collections/events/Events',
'text!templates/calendar/calendarTemplate.html',
'momentjs',
'fullcalendar',
],  function(_, Backbone, Event, Events, calendarTemplate, fullcalendar
){
var EventsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: document.getElementById("content"),
    render: function() {
        var self = this;
    var events = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('events'));
        var events = new Events(events);
    var jsevents = events.toJSON();
    this.el.innerHTML = _.template( calendarTemplate,{data : jsevents} );

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
         agenda: 'h:mm{ - h:mm}',
                     '': 'h(:mm)t',
             aspectRatio: 1.5,
             droppable: true,
             weekend: true,
     editable: true,
         defaultView: 'month',
         firstDay: 1,
         handleWindowResize: true,
             allDayDefault: false,
         firstHour: 7,
         columnFormat: {
             month: 'dddd',    
             week: 'ddd, dS', 
             day: 'dddd, MMM dS'
         },
         header: {
                 right: 'prev,next',
                 center: 'title',
                 left: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
         },
     selectable: true,
     selectHelper: true,
     select: function(start, end) {
                 var title = prompt('Event Title:');
             var eventData;
             if (title) {
             eventData = {
                title: title,
            start: start,
            end: end
            };
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);
            }
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
         },
         events: []
        });
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', jsevents );
    },        
});
return EventsView;
});
```

You can see my data for calendar are jsevents. So how can I load it into my fullcalendar? App on [GIT](https://github.com/makromat/calBB) Thanks for any help

**UPDATED:**

```
define([
'underscore',
'backbone',
'models/event/Event',
'collections/events/Events',
'text!templates/calendar/calendarTemplate.html',
'momentjs',
'fullcalendar',
],  function(_, Backbone, Event, Events, calendarTemplate, fullcalendar
){
var EventsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: document.getElementById("content"),
    render: function() {
        var self = this;
    var events = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('events'));
        var events = new Events(events);
    var jsevents = events.toJSON();
    this.el.innerHTML = _.template( calendarTemplate,{data : jsevents} );

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
         agenda: 'h:mm{ - h:mm}',
                     '': 'h(:mm)t',
             aspectRatio: 1.5,
             droppable: true,
             weekend: true,
     editable: true,
         defaultView: 'month',
         firstDay: 1,
         handleWindowResize: true,
             allDayDefault: false,
         firstHour: 7,
         columnFormat: {
             month: 'dddd',    
             week: 'ddd, dS', 
             day: 'dddd, MMM dS'
         },
         header: {
                 right: 'prev,next',
                 center: 'title',
                 left: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
         },
     selectable: true,
     selectHelper: true,
     select: function(start, end) {
                 var title = prompt('Event Title:');
             var eventData;
             if (title) {
             eventData = {
                title: title,
            start: start,
            end: end
            };
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);
                events.push(eventData);
                localStorage.setItem('events',JSON.stringify(events));
            }
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
         },
         events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
                callback(jsevents);
         }
        });
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', jsevents );
    },        
});
return EventsView;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this is the only problem but:

.start and .end need to be strings formatted like this: "2010-01-09T12:30:00"

See here http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_array/

You can use moments for this (included in fullcalendar anyway)

1. moment.unix(Number)
2. moment.toISOString() // 2013-02-04T22:44:30.652Z

or using format if timezone isn't accepted
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Note that you can also use a function as source (which allows for lazy fetching)

Comment: Thank you for help, I want store new events into local-storage as well.So I just don´t know how to create function which will add new events from backbone collection into fullcalendar. I have add [GIT](https://github.com/makromat/calBB)into question...

Comment: So you can let events or eventSources (if you want multiple sources) be function(s) that return the events that you want to show or rather that fullcalendar requests. The function signature looks like this: `function( start, end, timezone, callback )` and is documented [here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/)

Comment: I also think that it is at least intended that you should convert every item from your original array via `new Event({...})` before creating your collection via `new Events([event1, event2, ...])`

Comment: @Makromat you should also probably try to divide this into multiple  questions or something

Comment: @Makromat you can add events like [this](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)

Comment: Thanks for help... My calendar is now fully working and new events are stored into localstorage.

Comment: @Makromat accept my answer, post an answer with your solution, or edit mine so others with the same problem can benefit